# How to find source information about a function in Maxima?

Tags: maxima

Usually, the source codes (definitions) of the various functions provided by Maxima are stored in the files with the suffix `.mac` or `.lisp` within the installation directory of Maxima.

Is there a way to access these source codes within Maxima? (Like `M-x describe-function` within emacs?)

And more generally, how can find out where can the source file (in which the definition of a specific function is stored) be found?

I am familiar with the command `describe(some_function);` but that sort of the above info can not be found by this command.

For example I found the source file of the function `jacobi` in the file `numth.lisp` by guess. But guessing could be difficult for some other functions.

Comment: The definition of a function which is defined in the Maxima language can be displayed via `fundef(foo)` or `grind(foo)` where `foo` is the function in question. However, most built-in functions are defined in Lisp, and they can't be displayed that way. For better or worse, function implementations are probably best viewed by finding the file which contains them. (Depending on the Lisp implementation, some information might also be accessible via `(describe '$foo)` but that varies.)

Comment: @RobertDodier, Very interesting because `?describe(foo);` gives the file path of built-in functions that are defined in Lisp! Thank you very much.